# Transform JSON API data in Laravel or in iOS app

Tags: php, ios, json, rest, laravel

I am using Laravel fractal to transform my API data.

In my DB I have a timestamp like "2015-02-15 14:34" but I need to calculate that transform to "Time remaining" instead of outputting the timestamp.

So "2015-03-15 12:43" becomes Eg: "14 days and 4 hours"

Should I calculate the timestamp in Laravel using my fractal transformer with Carbon or should I send the timestamp as json to my iOS app then let the iOS app calculate and output the time remaining?

Eg:

```
public function transform(Model $model)
    {
        return [
            'time_remaining'  => Carbon::blabla->blabla($model->date_published);
        ];
    }
```

Or just send the json `date_published : "2015-02-14 14:30"` to the iOS app and let the app calculate that value to the time remaining before displaying it in the app view?

Also, the json will return a result of about 30 items, with pagination

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely send the date and time and not the human readable string. Two reasons:

1. The "... ago" **changes if time passes**. If you let the server handle this you have to make a new request if you want to update those "dates". If you do it on client side you don't have to. You can simply recalculate it because you have the actual timestamp
2. This human readable format is basically a **presentation concern**. In my opinion an API should provide raw data and the client should have to worry about how to format and display that data.

Comment: I agree. Also, I'd recommend returning the time in GMT, not the server's local time zone.

Comment: Thanks, then I will just send the json as it is stored and let the iOS app calculate the time remaining based on the json value. And since the project I am working on have a Elasticsearch package that doesnt allow nested objects I am already making a "inner-join" with the iOS app. The json returns id's thats actually foreign keys. so the app will receive the value eg "stateId : 2" then check the value "2" and return the state name that has that value. So "2" becomes eg "Alaska" instead. Its a bad sulotion I know. but since the backend/search engine cant handle those joins thats the only way